# Is there any way to add padding to ONLY the labelText in the TextFormField?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, text, padding

I am creating a Flutter app and I want to add horizontal padding to ONLY the labelText, not the hintText and the input text, in the TextFormField. I was using contentPadding but it adds padding to everything in the TextFormField. I tried looking for a solution but could not find anything.

[image] I want something like this in the picture, so that the labelText has extra padding on the left as compared to the input text.

Comment: You can simply add the padding like this `labelText: '             
        Text'`

Comment: It ends up increasing the width of the labelText container, instead of moving it a bit towards the right.

Answer (score 1):

contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.left(40.0),